# What is the memory overhead of a Java method?

Tags: java, memory

What is the memory overhead of a function in a class?

For example,

```
Class A
{
 int a
}

Class B
{
 int a
 int foo(int);
}
```

So 100 instances of class A should be 80 bytes. What about 100 instances of class B?

Comment: It's not called a function.  It's called a method.

Comment: lol, yes, it's called a method, and you would be better off doing a test.

Comment: it isn't testable, except by looking at the VM source, unless you do what others are doing and assume that the serialized form is the same as the in memory form.

Comment: Assuming that the serialized form has anything to do with the in memory representation is nonsense. I'd guess they did too much C programming, where such abuse is rampant.

Comment: well, you can also look at the VMs memory. "Create 100 objects of A, look at memory" same for B. I'll do a proper test for you in a bit.

Answer (score 11):

The overhead is... none.

The method definition and code address are stored in the Class object, which has a unique instance toward which every instance of your object points.
Since that would be the case, whether or not you added that method, the overhead for each individual object is nothing.

Comment: And I don't understand the down vote, since the answer is exact.

Comment: Not me, but this answer is not exactly correct. There is overhead in the maintainence of method definitions, even if the overhead is fixed and not dependent on the number of instances. Can we have a million methods? If no, then overhead exists.

Answer (score 4):

80 bytes since a method is not included in the object.  Unless you are also talking about the "vtable" type of thing, in which case probably 160 bytes.

Clarification on the 160 bytes.  The 160 would be if each object allocated its own vtable (which is one possible implementation).  Alternatively (and as is pointed out in the comments) a better way would be one vtable per class, which would mean 80 + the size of the pointer to the vtable (probably 4 or 8 bytes depending on the VM).  So 84 or 88 bytes.

This whole thing totally depends on the way the VM allocates memory and deals with non-final methods.  Without knowing how the particular VM is implemented neither question can be answered correctly.

Comment: Both classes have some kind of reference to their class (an equivalent to a C++ vtbl pointer). It's not like each object is going to carry around loads of class information on any kind of reasonable VM.

Comment: That is a VM specific implementation, as it is a C++ compiler specific imiplementation.

Comment: Tom, you seem to be overly Sun implementation centric when you comment on my answers.  If you cannot bother thinking that there are other possible VM implementations, well, I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 2):

As a few other people at least have said, the method is not stored in the serialization.

You can easily do a test to show this in this example with the following code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class SerializationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        serialize(true);
        serialize(false);
    }

    public static void serialize(boolean aOrB) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(aOrB ? new A() : new B());
            out.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file = new File("output.txt");
        System.out.println(file.length());
    }

    public static class A implements Serializable {
        int a = 0;
    }

    public static class B implements Serializable {
        int a = 0;

        public int foo(int a) {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

For me this prints out

```
48
48
```

Comment: Serialization does not necessarily reflect the way the data is allocated inside a running VM however.

Answer (score 2):

Objects of both classes will use about 20-24 bytes for 32/64-bit JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

The method is not stored in the serialized form. It's as simple as that.

**Edit:** As for objects in the VM during execution, the size should be constant, regardless of how many methods the class of the object has.

Answer (score 1):

Equal, 80! ( in short)

Answer (score -1):

Probably sizeof the v-table pointer rounded up to a multiple of 16.

Comment: Classes of both objects will have some sort of reference to their class.